# How to add fields from other modules in Drupal 6 Views?

Tags: views, ubercart

I have a Drupal 6 website with Ubercart 2 and the "Delivery time slots for Ubercart" module installed, and I have created a View to pull a custom report of order info. I need for that report to also include the delivery time slot chosen by the shopper on each order, but that module apparently does not have Views integration. Is there a way for me to pull the time slot value (and/or any other arbitrary database field that related to the other data I am pulling in, I assume based on the order ID) for each order into the view?

I appreciate any feedback! Thanks!

Comment: You can actually describe any table in your database to Views in a custom module (the equivalent of "providing views integration"). If you're comfortable with PHP you may find this helpful: http://grasmash.com/article/demystifying-views-api-developers-guide-integrating-views

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the below modules. They are meant for getting data directly from the database into views.

[Table Wizard](http://drupal.org/project/tw)

[Data Model](http://drupal.org/project/data)

If both of them doesn't suit your requirement then you could use the [Views Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) write php code directly into the view and collect the required fields using database queries.

You could also do the direct query with in the views template files.